# How to import CSV data into Typescript Object?

Tags: angular, typescript, csv-import

I working on a project for which I need to import a CSV file and parse the data into a typescript object.
The CSV files looks like this.

[My code works when CSV data is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyQoB.jpg)

[My code doesn't work when CSV data is like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ua0Go.jpg)

The second and third line has more empty value for first three values because first employee has three modes of travel. The code works perfectly fine when every fields have single values.

My typescript code looks like this.

````
    //read file from input
    this.fileReaded = fileInput.target.files[0];

    let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(this.fileReaded);
    let nestedLines: Memployee[] = [];
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      let d;
      let csv: any = reader.result;
      let allTextLines = csv.split(/\r|\n|\r/);
      let headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');
      let flag = true;
      console.log(allTextLines);
      let tarr: Memployee = new Memployee();
      for (let i = 1; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
        // split content based on comma
        let data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
        if (data[0] === '' || data[0] === null) {
          for (d of this.lines) {
            if (d.empcode == tarr.empcode) {
              d.modeoftravel.push(data[4]);
              console.log(data);
              break;
            }
          }
          // this.lines.forEach(
          //   d => {
          //     
          //   }
          // )
        } else {

          tarr.empcode = data[0];
          tarr.empname = data[2];
          tarr.emptype = data[2];
          tarr.empmobno = data[3];

          // log each row to see output 
          // console.log(tarr);
          console.log(tarr);
          this.lines.push(tarr);

        }
      }
      // all rows in the csv file 
      this.http.post('http://localhost:9500/api/master/employee/all', this.lines).subscribe(
        response => console.log('Success', response),
        error => console.log('Error', error)
      );
      console.log(this.lines);
    }
  } ```





But it doesn't work if the data has more than one line of value.
````

Comment: so basically the question is: why it is not working for the second and the third line?

Comment: It works for all the lines. But the problem is when one field has more than one values. It is written in cell below in excel. So the next object is in third row. I don't know how to read the second value.

Comment: You will understand if you see the image above.

Comment: Well, it seems the code is working as expected. I would say the file 2 is badly formatted. Can you require the file is correctly maintained? If not, you need to keep memory of the last line and assume the last value is the default, when a new value is not provided.

Comment: The code works fine as expected if the data is like in the first image. But client is asking for something like in second image.